# Why am I not getting the intended DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell hit in my DataGridViewControl?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am not getting the intended `DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell` hit whenever I click on a cell in my DataGridView control. I searched to no avail for a clue of why I am instead getting the `DataGridViewHitTestType.ColumnHeader` hit when I click on a cell in the first column, and `DataGridViewHitTestType.TopLeftHeader` when I click on a cell in the remaining two other columns.

My control has three columns, and its `SelectionMode` is set to `CellSelect`. Below is my code:

```
private void dgvYears_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
  {
     DataGridView.HitTestInfo hit = dgvYears.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
     if (hit.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell)
     {
       //What I want to do here....
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! It is really interesting behavior. Did you set the MultiSelect property of your DataGridView to false? If not please give a try.

Comment: Yes @stratever, it is set to false.

Comment: Well, i think i see what the real problem is. DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs provide coordinates relative to DataGridViewCell instead of DataGridView. You should handle MouseDown event which will provide MouseEventArgs as event argument and it will contain coordinates realtive to DataGridView control

Comment: Thanks a lot. What you suggested is what exactly what I needed to do. I have already named one of my methods after you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I should admit that this is not well documented, but `e.X` and `e.Y` in this event are relative to the upper left coordinate of the cell, while `HitTest` expects data grid view client coordinates.

To get the correct hit test, you can use something like this

```
var dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
var cellRect = dgv.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, false);
var hit = dgv.HitTest(e.X + cellRect.X, e.Y + cellRect.Y);
```

Comment: What you suggested works. However, handling the MouseDown event as suggested by @stratever is more convenient and straight forward for my current need. Regardless, you gave me a further insight in handling client coordinates. Appreciated.